# ember.js warning: not set a 'height' attribute for table

Tags: ember.js

I am newbie in EmberJS. I am working on an EmberJS project. I re-established the building environment. After that, one page of this webapp cannot be opened properly. There is a table on that page, the table doesn't show out. It works well before when the project was build in previous building environment which cannot be found any more...

I get this console log. It seems related with the issue, but I cannot find the solution.

```
WARNING: You did not set a `height` attribute for your table, but marked a header or footer to be fixed. This means that you have to set the table height via CSS. For more information please refer to:  https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-light-table/issues/446
```

The hbs code is as below:

```
{{#if (not asset)}}
    <div style="font-size:50px;" class="text-center">{{loading-spinner}}</div>
{{else}}
    <div class="flexbox-column height-full">
        <card class="fixed-card flexbox-shrink-none">
            <header class="height-auto flexbox-wrap">
                <div class="live-history-nav">
                    ...
                </div>
                    ...
            </header>
        </card>

        {{!-- State History --}}
        <div class="flexbox-grow-full {{if screenSize.isSmOrLarger "overflow-hidden"}}">
        {{#muuri/muuri-grid dragEnabled=true dragSort=true gridLayout=(hash fillGaps=true horizontal=screenSize.isSmOrLarger)}}

            {{#grid.item rowSize=(if screenSize.isXs 10 100) colSize=(if screenSize.isSmOrLarger (if eventsExpanded "33vw" "66vw")) isHidden=(contains 'map' hiddenList) as |item|}}
                    <card>
                        <header class={{dragHandleClass}} onclick={{if screenSize.isXs (action item.resizeAction (hash rowSize=1))}}>
                                
                            <title>
                                {{fa-icon 'map' size='lg' fixedWidth=true}}
                                {{t 'assetDetails.history.item.map.title'}}
                            </title>

                            <div class="checkbox margin-10-right">
                                <label>
                                    ...
                                </label>
                            </div>
                                
                        </header>
                            ...
                    </card>
                {{/grid.item}}

                {{!-- Event --}}
                {{#grid.item rowSize=(if screenSize.isXs 8 100) colSize=(if screenSize.isSmOrLarger (if eventsExpanded "66vw" "33vw")) isHidden=(contains 'events' hiddenList) as |item|}}
                    <card>
                        <header class={{dragHandleClass}} onclick={{if screenSize.isXs (action item.resizeAction (hash rowSize=1))}}>
                            {{!-- Resize button to minimize the content --}}
                            {{#if screenSize.isXs}}
                                ...
                            {{/if}}

                            <title class="margin-10-right">
                                {{fa-icon 'history' size='lg' fixedWidth=true}}
                                {{t 'assetDetails.history.item.events.title'}}
                            </title>

                            {{!-- Event selector --}}
                            {{events/event-selector-button
                                selectedCategoryIds=eventCategories
                                selectedTypeIds=eventTypes
                                onSubmit=(action 'onEventsSelected')}}

                            <div class="flexbox-grow-full" />

                            <subtitle>
                                  ...
                            </subtitle>
                        </header>

                        {{!-- Horiz scroll by adding overflow-x and min-width to table --}}
                        <content class="no-padding" style="overflow-x:auto;">
                            ...
                        </content>

                        <footer class="no-padding">
                            {{pagination-bar items=fetchEventsTask.lastSuccessful.value loadItemsPageAction=(action "loadItemsPage")}}
                        </footer>
                    </card>
                {{/grid.item}}

            {{/muuri/muuri-grid}}
        </div>
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: The link in the warning has all the details you will need:
"When setting {{t.head fixed=true}} or {{t.foot fixed=true}} the table body is wrapped inside an {{ember-scrollable}} container. Because of that, the height of the table cannot be determined and must be specified explicitly.

Currently, this is done by setting the height attribute, like {{table height="65vh"}}"

Comment: @digitalbreed Thank you very much for replying. Can you tell me where to put setting value for height attribute? I search the project, but could not find {{table height}}

Comment: The "height" is likely missing entirely, that's where the warning comes from. Search for "{{table" instead.